# Getting unable to locate element in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

Getting no such element: Unable to locate element error when writing with XPath or CSS. Please help

```
diver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ticket-title-input")).sendKeys("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using any of the following Xpaths,

```
//input[@id='ticket-title-input']
//div[@id='ticket-title-panel']//following-sibling::input
//div/following::input[@id='ticket-title-input']
```

Comment: Hi Shanilla thanks for your help. I tried with all the above options but still getting Unable to locate error. Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: Can you please share the error which you are getting and the code which you have tried.

Comment: @anonymous check weather the element present inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
diver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ticket-title-input")).sendKeys("hello");
```

`#` means you take element with id. Check [this post](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors) for details.

Comment: Hi Alexey thanks for your help. I tried with the above  but still getting Unable to locate error. Any suggestions on this please?

Answer (score 0):

[image]I believe that the element is present inside a frame, had a look at the top-most html line. 
I would suggest,

- find out the frame container of this element
- Switch to that frame and perform operation on that element.
- Switch back to the parent context

Hope this helps.
Please share the entire html for better response.

Comment: I have added the HTML screenshot above.Please let me know how to handle Frames here. Thanks in advance Kshetra Mohan Prusty

Answer (score 0):

As guessed, the element is present inside a frame.

1. Please switch to the frame with below xpath.

   > //iframe[@src = 'vcr/1404/Pages/newTicketV2.html']

Pass the instance of web element of the iframe above as argument to the

```
driver.switchTo().frame(_element);
```

2. Then perform the interaction with the intended element

   > //input[@id = 'ticket-title-input']
3. After the interaction is over and when you think you dont have interact with any other element inside that frame, switch to default content